# Using Dates with RSQLite

Tags: r

How do you write a SQL query with a date using RSQLite. Here is an example below. The `dbGetQuery` does not return any rows.

```
require(RSQLite)
require(ggplot2)
data(presidential)
m <- dbDriver("SQLite")
tmpfile <- tempfile('presidential', fileext='.db')
conn <- dbConnect(m, dbname=tmpfile)
dbWriteTable(conn, "presidential", presidential)
dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM presidential WHERE Date(start) >= Date('1980-01-01')")
```

Comment: I believe SQLite does not have any native date types. I have always stored them as text. For instance, all the SQLite date/time functions (like `date()`) act on a string, not a "date object" or integer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just to illustrate, this works fine:

```
tmpfile <- tempfile('presidential', fileext='.db')
conn <- dbConnect(m, dbname=tmpfile)
p <- presidential
p$start <- as.character(p$start)
p$end <- as.character(p$end)

dbWriteTable(conn, "presidential", p)
dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM presidential WHERE start >= '1980-01-01'")
```

You can read about the lack of native date types in SQLite in the docs [here](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). I've been using strings as dates for so long in SQLite that I'd actually forgotten about the issue completely.

And yes, I've written a small R function that converts any Date column in a data frame to character. For simple comparisons, keeping them in `YYYY-MM-DD` is enough, and if I need to do arithmetic I convert them after the fact in R.

Comment: @joran - would you be willing to share that function which converts the date column?

Comment: @boshek It's nothing special, since in this particular case I know with 100% certainty that the format will always be YYYY-MM-DD, so I just loop over columns, test if it's a Date class and then coerce it to character.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from @joran's answer, here's a simple function to convert date columns to string for a data.frame.

```
mutate(df, across(where(is.Date), ~ format(.x, "%Y.%m.%d")))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to https://github.com/r-dbi/RSQLite/issues/351#issuecomment-903096985

Add extended_types = TRUE in dbConnect() makes RSQLite support Date type when writing and reading data from SQLite

```
library(RSQLite)
con <- dbConnect(SQLite(), extended_types = TRUE)

dbWriteTable(con, "test", data.frame(date = Sys.Date()))
str(dbReadTable(con, "test"))
#> 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  1 variable:
#>  $ date: Date, format: "2021-08-21"
```

Answer (score 0):

As @joran suggests keeping dates in text in SQLlite seems like the best way to go for the time being.

I used @Richard Knight's approach for conversion in, but with ISO format, to change the date to string before writing the dataframe:

```
local_df %>% mutate(across(where(lubridate::is.Date), ~ format(.x, "%Y-%m-%d")))
```

Manipulating the dates remotely can be done using sql translation, particularly:

```
remote_df %>% mutate(date_as_number = julianday(date_as_string))
remote_df %>% mutate(date_as_string = date(date_as_number))
```

N.b. that is `date` not `as.Date` in the second one. This is because `as.Date` will get translated to `CAST(date_as_number AS DATE)` whereas what we want is to use SQLLite's `date()` function with a floating point number as returned by `julianday()`.

Mapping the remote datestrings back into dates can be done automatically, if you :

```
collect <- function(remote_df, ...) {
  raw = remote_df %>% dplyr::collect(...)
  isoDateString = function(x) return(is.character(x) & all(na.omit(stringr::str_detect(x,"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}"))) & !all(is.na(x)))
  raw = raw %>% mutate(across(where(isoDateString), ~ as.Date(.x, "%Y-%m-%d")))
  maybeJulian = function(x) {return(is.double(x) & all(na.omit(x>2440587.5)) & all(na.omit(x<2488069.5)) & !all(is.na(x)))}
  raw = raw %>% mutate(across(matches(".*(D|d)ate.*") & where(maybeJulian), ~ as.Date(.x-2440587.5, "1970-01-01")))
  return(raw)
}
```

The apparently random numbers in the `maybeJulian` function correspond to `1970-01-01` and `2100-01-01`