# RSQLite - dbWriteTable - field.type - How to get proper Date format?

Tags: r, rsqlite

> `RSQLite::dbWriteTable` function, properly pass Dates from `df` to **db**.

I have some date fields on my df, and when I try to write the table on an **SQLite** db using the aforementioned function and setting `field.types = c(col1 = "Date", col2 = "Date")` it writes those date fields as a number instead of date, e.g. :

> `"2018-12-01"`   becomes   `17866`

Here's my complete code:

```
dbWriteTable(db, "table", df, overwrite = T, append = F, 
          field.types = c(Col1 = "Date", Col2  = "Date"))
```

This actually writes the `"table"` on the `SQLite` `db` with proper `Date` format for such columns, but the values inside the cells are not dates, they remain numbers such as  `17866`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462086/using-dates-with-rsqlite) I found someone suggesting a workaround, transforming the date as.character.

> Is there a *proper* way to pass a **date** value to an **SQLite db**?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing now, I never actually found a way to do this as described on my question. In the end I went for the workaround that I mentioned in my question:

> transform all the date variables in text before writing on the SQLite
>   DB.

Comment: Hi @Mirko, I am facing the same problem. Could you post your solution? I have a small shiny app with a dateInput control but when the date goes into the sqlite database it shows as integers.

Answer (score -1):

An "extended_types" argument may work at DBconnection.

```
db <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(),
                     dbname = "xxx",
                     extended_types = T) # this point
```